# Why does the most negative int value cause an error about ambiguous function overloads?

Tags: c++, integer, overloading, negative-number, ambiguous-call

I'm learning about function overloading in C++ and came across this:

```
void display(int a)
{
    cout << "int" << endl;
}

void display(unsigned a)
{
    cout << "unsigned" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int i = -2147483648;
    cout << i << endl; //will display -2147483648
    display(-2147483648);
}
```

From what I understood, any value given in the `int` range (in my case `int` is 4 byte) will call `display(int)` and any value outside this range will be ambiguous (since the compiler cannot decide which function to call). It is valid for the complete range of `int` values except its min value i.e. `-2147483648` where compilation fails with the error

> call of overloaded `display(long int)` is ambiguous

But taking the same value to an `int` and printing the value gives `2147483648`. I'm literally confused with this behavior.

Why is this behavior observed only when the most negative number is passed? (The behavior is the same if a `short` is used with `-32768` - in fact, in any case where the negative number and positive number have the same binary representation)

Compiler used: g++ (GCC) 4.8.5

Comment: Int's min value is "throwing a compiler error". What error? You should include it in the question

Comment: I see `call of overloaded ‘display(long int)’ is ambiguous`.

Comment: @crashmstr Yes, the error should be in the question

Comment: Not related, but you should update the compiler. There is already GCC 7.1.

Comment: Yeah the same what @crashmstr has mentioned!

Comment: Here's my guess: `typeof(-2147483648) != int`. The literal is `2147483648`, which is too big for an `int`, so it's a `long`, and it's being negated

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, the behaviour is same with MSVC++ 14.0 compiler

Comment: perhaps somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771409/why-is-it-ambiguous-to-call-overloaded-ambiglong-and-ambigunsigned-long-with

Comment: Possible duplicate of [large negative integer literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511598/large-negative-integer-literals)

Comment: @infiniteloop I'm not saying that's because of the compiler. (That's why I said 'not related'.) I just suggest getting an ungrade.

Comment: [Casting minimum 32-bit integer (-2147483648) to float gives positive number (2147483648.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11536389/995714), [(-2147483648> 0) returns true in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14695118/995714), [Warning: this decimal constant is unsigned only in ISO C90](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9941261/995714)

Comment: [Why does MSVC pick a long long as the type for -2147483648?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34725215/995714)

Comment: Interestingly, g++ (6.4 and 7.1, at least) don't complain that `int j{-2147483648};` is a narrowing conversion.  Almost worth a question in itself, that.  It's probably related to allowing (e.g.) `long long` constexpr values such as `2147483647LL` to be narrowed in initialization.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

This is a very subtle error.  What you are seeing is a consequence of there being no negative integer literals in C++.  If we look at [lex.icon] we get that a *integer-literal*,

> *integer-literal*
>           *decimal-literal integer-suffix<sub>opt</sub>*
>           [...]

can be a *decimal-literal*,

> *decimal-literal:*
>           *nonzero-digit*
>           *decimal-literal ’ <sub>opt</sub> digit*

where *digit* is `[0-9]` and *nonzero-digit* is `[1-9]` and the suffix par can be one of `u`, `U`, `l`, `L`, `ll`, or `LL`.  Nowhere in here does it include `-` as being part of the decimal literal.

In §2.13.2, we also have:

> An *integer literal* is a sequence of digits that has no period or exponent part, with optional separating single quotes that are ignored when determining its value. An integer literal may have a prefix that specifies its base and a suffix that specifies its type. The lexically first digit of the sequence of digits is the most significant. **A *decimal* integer literal (base ten) begins with a digit other than 0 and consists of a sequence of decimal digits.**

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Which means the `-` in `-2147483648` is the unary `operator -`.  That means `-2147483648` is actually treated as `-1 * (2147483648)`.  Since `2147483648` is one too many for your `int` it is promoted to a `long int` and the ambiguity comes from that not matching.

If you want to get the minimum or maximum value for a type in a portable manner you can use:

```
std::numeric_limits<type>::min();  // or max()
```

Comment: `-2147483647 - 1` would also work without warning as a negative literal expression

Comment: Or `INT_MIN` for the least verbose option. Less generic, though.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Can you kindly explain me this case `display(2147483649);`. Why can't it call the unsigned int func in this case? and why it treats the arg `2147483649` as long int instead of unsigned int?

Comment: @infiniteloop Decimal integer literals go from `int` to `long int` to `long long int`.  You wlll never get an unsigned type for a decimal literal unless you use the `u`/`U` suffix.

Comment: @NathanOliver  So, until explicitly given an unsigned int variable or unsigned cast, the unsigned function cannot be called?

Comment: In this example yes.  To call `display(unsigned a)` you need either `display(1234u);` or `display(static_cast<unsigned>(1234));` or `unsigned foo = 1234; display(foo);`

Answer (score 36):

The expression `-2147483648` is actually applying the `-` operator to the constant `2147483648`. On your platform, `int` can't store `2147483648`, it must be represented by a larger type. Therefore, the expression `-2147483648` is not deduced to be `signed int` but a larger signed type, `signed long int`.

Since you do not provide an overload for `long` the compiler is forced to choose between two overloads that are both equally valid. Your compiler should issue a compiler error about ambiguous overloads.

Answer (score 4):

**Expanding on others' answers**

---

**To clarify why the OP is confused, first**: consider the `signed int` binary representation of `2147483647`, below.

[image: Largest signed int]

---

**Next, add one to this number**: giving another `signed int` of `-2147483648` (which the OP wishes to use)
[image: Smallest signed int]

---

**Finally:** we can see why the OP is confused when `-2147483648` compiles to a `long int` instead of a `signed int`, since it clearly fits in 32 bits.

But, as the current answers mention, the unary operator (`-`) is applied ***after*** resolving `2147483648` which is a `long int` and does NOT fit in 32 bits.