# How is it possible that an octal literal can be negative?

Tags: c++, octal

Why is `n` in

```
const int n = -0123;
```

an octal literal? I thought that all octal literals had to start with a 0, and this one doesn't since it starts with a negative.

It's a small point I know but It's causing me great confusion!

Comment: Is the `-` part of the literal?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Exactly! That's my point!

Comment: I'm pretty sure `-0123` starts with a zero. Likewise you can do `-0xFF` for -255 and `-0b010` for -2.

Comment: No, I mean the literal is `0123`, and you've applied the unary `-` operator to the resulting value.

Comment: Pardon me? Now I'm even more confused. -0123 is a literal, no?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What he said. It's just a way to indicate you want it to be the negative of what you entered.

Comment: `n` is not a literal of any kind; it's an identifier.

Comment: I don't understand why you are confused. For example... `-010` is `- octal 10` which is `-8` in decimal.

Comment: `0123` is the literal, `-` is the unary minus

Comment: For more fun see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469214/why-does-the-most-negative-int-value-cause-an-error-about-ambiguous-function-ove/45469321#45469321

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How is it possible that an octal literal can be negative?

There are no negative integer literals, only positive. The literal here is 0123 which does start with a 0 and is thus octal. `-` in that expression is the unary minus operator.

Answer (score 8):

This is absolutely true. However, the same applies to all integer literals - decimal, hexadecimal, octal, and binary. In fact, there are no negative integer literals. Expressions such as `-1` apply the unary minus operator to the value represented by the literal, which may involve implicit type conversions ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)).

Answer (score 1):

*You seem to be mildly confused about literals, so:*

In short, a literal is a way to describe a type that can be seen *literally* in the code. An integer is a literal because when you write, for example `4` in your code. You can *literally* see that it's the number four, and numbers are interpreted as `int`s by default unless they have a dot (`.`) after them, or any of the other valid suffixes.

However, you can tell to interpret it as an unsigned by writing `4u`. Now you can literally see that it's the number 4 interpreted as an unsigned. Likewise, the value `"Hello World"` is a string literal because you can tell in the code that it is the string `"Hello World`". On the other hand, a user defined class `Person` has no literal way of being seen in the code. In C++14 you can however make user defined literals, but for a `Person` that would still arguably make no sense. The standard library uses this in the `<chrono>` header, defining literals such as `s`, `ms` and `ns` for seconds, milliseconds and nanoseconds respectively.

When writing the octal `-0123` you tell to interpret it as an octal value in the same way `0xFF` literally interprets as a hex. The `-` sign is simply a way to apply the unary negation operator on the number `0123`.