# Why can I not initialize a long long as expected?

Tags: c++, 64-bit, long-long

My VC2017 compiler is showing this behavior, can someone explain me what is going on?:

```
long long testLLSigned0 = LLONG_MIN; // OK, equal to -922129006921510580
long long testLLSigned1 = -922129006921510580i64‬; // Error, invalid suffix i64 on integer constant
long long testLLSigned2 = -922337203685477580i64; // OK!
long long testLLSigned3 = -922337203685477580LL; // OK!
long long testLLSigned4 = -‭62129006921510911‬LL; // Error, use of undeclared identifier ‭62129006921510911‬LL
long long testLLSigned5 = -‭62129006921510911i64‬; // Error, use of undeclared identifier ‭62129006921510911i64
```

Comment: Unicode Character 'LEFT-TO-RIGHT OVERRIDE' (U+202D) is causing the "number" to be an identifier.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469214/why-does-the-most-negative-int-value-cause-an-error-about-ambiguous-function-ove/45469321#45469321 The literal `-922129006921510580` is not the same as the value `-922129006921510580`.

Comment: @Eljay, thanks for your answer, never heard about it. How do I solve this?

Comment: I don't know how to solve that in VC2017.  I don't use VC2017, I use Vim.

Comment: Okay, but Vim is not a compiler :-) you probably mean g++. I try it right away on g++

Comment: @DrumM changing the compiler (probably) won't help. You need to edit the file and remove the unicode control character.

Comment: try this: `long long testLLSigned1 = -922129006921510580i64;
long long testLLSigned2 = -922337203685477580i64;
long long testLLSigned3 = -922337203685477580LL;
long long testLLSigned4 = -62129006921510911LL;
long long testLLSigned5 = -62129006921510911i64;` **I only removed unicode characters**

Comment: Indeed, with g++ I got "error: stray '\342'". It was even copied in this text. When I removed all of them I only got the following error: "unable to find numeric literal operator ‘operator""i64’" So this means, LL works.

Comment: From [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/numeric-boolean-and-pointer-literals-cpp?view=vs-2017): [...]`The i64 suffix is still supported but should be avoided because it is specific to Microsoft and is not portable.`[...]

Comment: Wow, thanks all of you guys. I try to formalize it in an answer. The biggest reason of this failure is due to copying values from the Windows Calculator(!!)  (head against the wall...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Eljay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4641116/eljay), [NathanOliver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4342498/nathanoliver), [eerorika](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2079303/eerorika) & [user1810087](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1810087/user1810087), I solved it.

The biggest reason the code didn't compile was due to copying the calculated values from the Windows calculator (!) into any modern editor (!). The value 62129006921510911 was copied inside the editor with **invisible** unicode characters! The result when pasted in vim showed us: -`<202d>62129006921510911<202c>LL`

Side note: use the LL syntax, the i64 syntax is specific to Microsoft and is not portable.

Comment: see [How to stop Windows 10 Calculator from enclosing copied text in 202D and 202C Unicode characters?](https://superuser.com/q/1361155/241386)