# Integer literal that matches int64_t for both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms?

Tags: c++, x86, integer, x86-64, literals

Consider a piece of code below. Is there an integer literal that would compile on both 32-bit and 64-bit platforms?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

void f(double)
{
    std::cout << "double\n";
}

void f(int64_t)
{
    std::cout << "int64_t\n";
}

int main()
{
    f(0L);  // works on 64-bit fails on 32-bit system
    f(0LL); // fails on 64-bit but works on 32-bit system

    f(int64_t(0));              // works on both, but is ugly...
    f(static_cast<int64_t>(0)); // ... even uglier

    return 0;
}
```

On platforms where `int64_t` is `long`, `0LL` is a different type and overload resolution doesn't prefer it vs. `double`.

When `int64_t` is `long long` (including on Windows x64), we have the same problem with `0L`.

(`0LL` is `int64_t` in both the 32-bit and x86-64 Windows ABIs (LLP64), but other OSes use x86-64 System V which is an LP64 ABI.  And of course something portable to non-x86 systems would be nice.)

Comment: You could make your own `_s64` suffix. `constexpr std::int64_t operator "" _s64(unsigned long long v) { return static_cast<std::int64_t>(v); }`  You'll note that *unary minus* is applied after-the-fact.  That's a C-ism that C++ inherited, and can sometimes cause subtle problems for some literal numeric edge cases.

Comment: I'm tempted to say `explicit void f(double)` so integer arguments promote to int64_t but that isn't valid. Make a single templated function and check if the argument is integer or floating point with `if constexpr`?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow You can't use explicit, but one thing you can do to stop implicit conversions is to add to the overload set `template <typename T> ret_type func_name(T) = delete;`.  If this is a better match, i.e, wouldn't need an implicit conversion, then a compiler error is raised

Comment: @NathanOliver The idea wasn't to delete but to make the uint64_t version the better match when the argument is ambiguous. The `f(0LLU)` wouldn't try to convert to double.

Answer (score 8):

You can make a custom [user defined literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) for `int64_t` like

```
constexpr int64_t operator "" _i64(unsigned long long value) 
{ 
    return static_cast<std::int64_t>(value);
}
```

and then your function call would become

```
f(0_i64);
```

This will give you an incorrect value if you try to use the literal `-9223372036854775808` for the reason stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469214/why-does-the-most-negative-int-value-cause-an-error-about-ambiguous-function-ove/45469321#45469321)

Comment: Could also be `constexpr`.

Comment: @Evg: even `consteval`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Doesn't `consteval` mean this function can only be called at compile time?

Comment: @Evg Good idea.  Added.

Comment: Can you call an `operator ""` function with a non-constant argument?  I assumed it could only work on literals.

Comment: @PeterCordes Good point.  You can call the operator since it is a function like `operator""_i64(foo);`, but that is kind of weird.  Not sure which I prefer, constexpr or consteval.