# positive values ​instead negative values of integer_literals

Tags: c++, c, libclang

In the source code, I have a negative int literal.  When I parse the source code through libclang, the integer_leteral functions clang_Cursor_Evaluate and clang_EvalResult_getAsInt return a positive value for this.

For example, I had int a = -555 in the source code.  If you get this integer_value and call the clang_Cursor_Evaluate and clang_EvalResult_getAsInt functions for it, the latter will simply return 555. Why is this happening?

Comment: There are no negative integer literals in  C (and I believe C++). There are positive literals (or zero) and unary `-` operator.

Comment: related/dupe/fun read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469214/why-does-the-most-negative-int-value-cause-an-error-about-ambiguous-function-ove/45469321#45469321

Answer (score 4):

There are no negative integer literals in C and C++. When you have something like `-555` that's an integer literal `555` and a unary minus operator. A decimal integer has a signed integral type that won't be promoted, so that works out to the expected type and value.

Comment: is there a rationale behind this choice of representation?

Comment: @helix As far as I can tell it has always been like that in C++, C and also C's predecessors. I guess it is probably because forming of preprocessor tokens would otherwise get more complex, e.g. `-1` could be a single literal token or a `-` token followed by a literal token depending on the token preceding it, e.g. `1 -1` vs `= -1`.