Why can't -2147483648 represented in hex literal?
Based on C++ documentation the size to hold hex literal grows from int -> unsigned int -> long -> unsigned long -> long long -> unsigned long long.
But I wonder how to specify hex literal -2147483648?
By right it should be possible since that value can be fitted into int.
But compiling the code below gives me the following error.

unary minus operator applied to unsigned type, result still unsigned

#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
int main()
{
    std::cout << -0x80000000 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

The maximum negative literal I can represent using hex literal is -0x7fffffff`.

0x80000000 is already -2147483648 when stored in a 32 bit signed integer (assuming 2's complement). No need to add -.  See demo.

Assuming two's complement, the "max" negative 32-bit number is 0x80000000. You should not negate it.

The unary - is not part of the numeric literal.  (Numeric literals are always positive.)  That's why people get surprised at things like auto i = -0x8000000; is an unsigned int (well, depending on your platform) because of how numeric literals get promoted first, and then then unary - is applied.

Here's what I do constexpr auto operator""_si_neg(unsigned long long n) { return static_cast<signed int>(-n); } and then 0x8000'0000_si_neg.  (I have a whole suite of suffixes for signed, signed negated, and unsigned for the types and the fixed types.)

related, maybe a dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469214/why-does-the-most-negative-int-value-cause-an-error-about-ambiguous-function-ove/45469321#45469321

Learn about std""numeric limits and check what they are on your system. The actual representation (hex, binary, octal or decimal) doesn't matter it is the bits that count.

Use std::numeric_limits<int>::min() from <limits> header. For other values than the minimum, use static_cast before negation.


Why can't -2147483648 represented in hex literal?

First, - is not a part of an integer constant. In -2147483648 or -0x80000000, he source code 2147483648 or 0x80000000 is parsed separately, and - is applied later as an operator.
Second, a 32-bit int cannot represent 2,147,483,648, so, in a C++ implementation with 32-bit int, 0x80000000 becomes an unsigned int. The type of an unsuffixed hexadecimal integer literal is the first of these that can represent its value:

int
unsigned int
long int
unsigned long int
long long int
unsigned long long int

(It is the same for binary and octal integer literals. For decimal, the unsigned types are not considered.)
The largest value a 32-bit int can represent is 2,147,483,647. So the first type in the list that can represent 2,147,483,648 is unsigned int.
So 0x80000000 is an unsigned int, and -0x80000000 performs a negation on that value. The result type is also unsigned int, so the negation merely wraps modulo 232, yielding the same value, 2,147,483,648.
Options for creating a constant for −2,147,483,648 in C++ source code include -1-0x7fffffff, -2*0x40000000, and (int) -0x80000000L.


But I wonder how to specify hex literal -2147483648?

Assuming your system is using 2's complement to represent negative integer values, then the proper hex literal that corresponds to -2147483648 as a signed 32 bit integer is 0x80000000.
You should not negate it as you did.
The following minimal example demostrates it:
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int32_t a = 0x80000000;
    std::cout << a << "\n";
}

Output:
-2147483648

Live demo

This “answer” does not answer the question that was asked in the title; it does not say why −2,147,483,648 cannot be represented in a hexadecimal literal.

It answers the question mentioned in the body (quoted in the beginning of my answer). I think it is at least a partial answer, and therefore useful.

The OP asks:

But I wonder how to specify hex literal -2147483648? By right it should be possible since that value can be fitted into int.

It is not possible to represent the value -2147483648 (or any other negative value) as an integer literal. This is true both for decimal and hexadecimal literals. That's because there are no negative integer literals.
CppReference explains:

There are no negative integer literals. Expressions such as -1 apply the unary minus operator to the value represented by the literal, which may involve implicit type conversions.

An unsuffixed hexadecimal integer literal has the first type of int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int, or unsigned long long int that can represent it.
If an unsuffixed hex literal has the same number of bits as one of these integer types, but the hex literal contains a 1 at the location where the signed integer type has its sign bit, then the type of the hex literal is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the 1  contributes to its magnitude, rather than its sign.
You can demonstrate this using the typeid operator.
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout
        << "0x80000000 has type " << typeid(0x80000000).name() << ".\n"
        << "Its value is " << 0x80000000 << '\n';
    return 0;
}

Output:
0x80000000 has type unsigned int.
Its value is 2147483648

The next best thing
Assuming that type int uses a 32-bit, two's complement representation, you can create the value -2147483648 by casting 0x80000000 to type int:
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout
        << "static_cast<int>(0x80000000) has type " 
        << typeid(static_cast<int>(0x80000000)).name() << ".\n"
        << "Its value is " << static_cast<int>(0x80000000) << '\n';
    return 0;
}

Output:
static_cast<int>(0x80000000) has type int.
Its value is -2147483648


Re “When a hexadecimal integer literal contains a 1 at the location where a signed integer type has its sign bit…”: It is not clear this is wrong, but it is not a correct explanation either, in that it is not going to help somebody learning C++ how these things work. The binary for 128 or 0x80, 10000000, has a 1 bit where a signed eight-bit char has its sign bit, but the hex literal 0x80 is not an unsigned char. So this rule as stated is not correct. Unless there is good reason otherwise, answers ought to follow the rules in the C++ standard:…

… An unsuffixed decimal integer literal has the first type of int, long int, or long long int that can represent it, and an unsuffixed binary, octal, or hexadecimal  integer literal has the first of int, unsigned int, long int, unsigned long int, long long int, or unsigned long long int, that can represent it.

Thanks, @Eric Postpischil. I have edited my answer to reflect your comments.
