# Why does function overloading generate an ambiguous error in C++?

Tags: c++, c++14, overloading, short, ambiguous

In the following code snippets, In function call `f(1)`, `1` is a literal of type `int` and in first function `void f(double d)` argument type is `double` and second function `void f(short int i)` argument type is **short int**.

Here `1` is an `int` type not a `double` type, then **Why does compiler generated ambiguous error?**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void f(double d)  // First function
{
    cout<<d<<endl;
}

void f(short int i) // Second function
{
    cout<<i<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    f(1); // 1 is a literal of type int
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it ambiguous to call overloaded ambig(long) and ambig(unsigned long) with an integer literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8771409/why-is-it-ambiguous-to-call-overloaded-ambiglong-and-ambigunsigned-long-with)

Comment: I.e. "1 is an int type and short int is also int type" is an incorrect statement.

Comment: `int` and `short int` are different types. `short` is not some sort of qualifier for `int`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Because, as your comment notes, `1` is a literal of type `int`.

To the compiler, an implicit conversion of `int` to `short int` is equally as valid as an implicit conversion of `int` to `double` (*cf*. the C++ language standard, §13.3).

Thus, because the compiler can't decide between the `double` and `short int` overloads, it gives up and issues a diagnostic.

Note that the *magnitude* of the function parameter doesn't matter: just the type.

(It would be annoying if the compiler chose, at runtime, the `short int` overload if the calling argument was appropriate, and the `double` one in other instances.)

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, it is a bit ironic that ``f(0)`` can indeed cause a different overload resolution than ``int a=0; f(a);``. But that's why ``nullptr`` was added, of course.